# Salesforce Metadata API Deployment Not pushing System Permissions

Tags: salesforce

How do you get the System Permissions to be pulled?

I am working on building a [Metadata deployment](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/index.htm) for our company, and part of the deployment includes creating several new profiles.  We are trying to capture all of the permissions for these profiles, but can't seem to get the system permissions to match in our test runs.

I know that when you retrieve the profile object, [what you get is dynamic, based on what other object you are retrieving.](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/daas/salesforce_migration_guide.pdf) (see Chap 4 bullet 2)

The Following System Permissions are different between our source and destination environment

```
Customize Application
Manage Connections
Manage Custom Report Types
Manage Dashboards
Manage Public Documents
Manage Public List Views
Manage Public Reports
Manage Public Templates
Manage Translation
Manage Users
Modify All Data
Reset User Passwords and Unlock Users
+ Send Email
Transfer Record
View All Data
```

note: + indicates added in the destination.  All others are lost.

Comment: Are you deploying the profiles too?

Comment: Yes.  The new Profiles get created and all the field/Object security rules get created, but the System Permissions just don't match.

Comment: I have the same problem. I cannot find any good information on how to deploy the "System Permissions" on a profile or permission set (such as "Modify All Data" and "Author Apex"). Did you ever find any more information or a solution?

Comment: I was not able to get a solution.  We ended up just auditing the difference, and managing them in each environment manually.

Answer (score -2):

In order to use the Metadata API - the user must have the "API Enabled" and the "Modify All Data" permissions.

Comment: While I don't disagree with your statement, I don't see the relevance to the question.  I am trying to deploy the permissions not access the Metadata API.  I had the deployment working via the API, but it wasn't deploying the same permission in the source and destination environments.